# I get the the queryset, how to get the relative objects?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I get the relative objects from queryset, but it have a further relative query, how to get those objects?

```
class PropertyTaxItem(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)

class Property(models.Model):
    citizens = models.ManyToManyField(Citizen, null=True, through = 'Ownership',help_text="a property could belong to multiple citizens")

class Citizen(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, help_text = 'First name')
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, help_text = 'Last name')
```

my getting the citzien part:

```
items = PropertyTaxItem.objects.filter(i_status='active').select_related('property_id').prefetch_related('property_id.citizens')
for i in items:
    pp.pprint(i.citizens.__dict__)
```

the output is:

```
{'_db': None,
'_fk_val': 10092,
'_inherited': False,
'core_filters': {'property__pk': 10092},
'creation_counter': 69,
'instance': <Property: 306 GASHIHA, KAGINA, Kicukiro,Kicukiro>,
'model': <class 'citizen.models.Citizen'>,
'prefetch_cache_name': 'citizens',
'query_field_name': 'property',
'reverse': False,
'source_field_name': 'asset_property',
'symmetrical': False,
'target_field_name': 'owner_citizen',
'through': <class 'property.models.Ownership'>}
```

but I want get the items of citizens like:

```
{'id': 18980,
 'first_name': 'Jack',
 'last_name' : 'blablabla',
 ....
 }
```

how to do it?

Comment: Is that the full output, or there is more?

Comment: this is not full output of list, since there is error for I want to fetch citizen.id or citizen.first_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. You are querying `PropertyTaxItem` which foreign keys to `Property`, which then has multiple `Citizen`s. This would be a correct query to select the related 'property`s and prefetch the`property.citizens`

```
items = PropertyTaxItem.objects.filter(i_status='active').select_related('property').prefetch_related('property__citizens')
```

You can access the citizens like this:

```
for i in items:
    citizens = i.property.citizens.all() # now you have a queryset of citizens. 
    # To get a list of dictionaries, you can call `.values()` on the queryset.
    pp.pprint(citizens.values())
```

Another possible problem you will have is that `citizens` uses a custom through model. There are some limitations on `ManyToManyField` query sets when using custom though models.